# Any ideas on how to send a filename attributed with a file when using BufferedOuput/Input Stream?

Tags: java, networking, client-server, bufferedinputstream

I am sending a few jpegs (and sometimes zip) files. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to send the filename (or a custom filename) with the file, rather than definin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a DataOutputStream/DataInputStream and use writeUTF()/readUTF() the filename before sending the length of the file, followed by the file.

Basicly you have to have a small protocol of your own which sends the infomration you need.

Something like

```
DataOutputStream dos
byte[] bytes;

dos.writeUTF(filename);
dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
dos.write(bytes);
```

to read

```
DataInputStream dis
String filename = dis.readUTF();
int length = dis.readInt();
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
dis.readFully(bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks,I did think that sending it in a different stream is an option but I was hoping that I might have missed something that allows you to write the name as an overhead of the file you send.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though, I think I will have to go with this option!